# Why does my app crash on single choice?

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

I'm making a single choice list out of all bounded bluetoothdevices. And I try just toast a message "SUCCESS" once choice is made.
I have 2 files in my projekt. MainActivity.java:

```
import package_name.DeviceChooser.listenForDeviceChoose;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements listenForDeviceChoose{

public void chooseDevice (View view) {
        deviceArray.clear();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                deviceArray.add(device.getName());
            }
        }
        DeviceChooser deviceChooser = new DeviceChooser();
        deviceChooser.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DeviceChooser");
    }
}
```

and DeviceChooser.java:

```
public class DeviceChooser extends DialogFragment {

    public interface listenForDeviceChoose {
        public void clickDevice(int i);
    }

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               builder.setSingleChoiceItems(cs, 1,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      ((listenForDeviceChoose) builder).clickDevice(which);
                   }
               });
} 
}
```

App gets crashed when I do my choice. Why? And where can I learn all those small things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you posted throws a `ClassCastException`
because is `MainActivity`   that implements the interface. You should cast the activity's object not the Dialog's builder.

```
((listenForDeviceChoose) getActivity()).clickDevice(which);
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. +1 and accepting. Where can I learn all these small things? I cant even set up examples out of google correctly. I google on every detail every small thing. Does it comes with a time and experience?

Comment: I can't really answer. It takes time and patience. You could read thinking in java vol 1 and effective java